# Creating a Node server that relays file to another server(multer)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, multipartform-data, multer

In my project, the setup is:

1. Client -> relay server
2. Relay server -> Resource server

I am creating an API which will save the data on the Resource server. So, I have to upload the file to my Relay server first. In the relay server, I am using multer to parse the multipart form data and then send the file to my Resource server

```
const multer = require('multer')
const axios = require("axios");
const upload = multer();


router.post('/file', upload.single('featureData'), function (req, res, next) {
  
  const requestData = new FormData()
  requestData.append('featureData', req.file.buffer, {
    filename: req.file.originalname,
    encoding: req.file.encoding,
    mimeType: req.file.mimeType
  })

  // sending file to resource server
  axios.post(process.env.HOST + '/file', requestData, {
    method: 'post',
    // headers: {...requestData.getHeaders(), 'Content-Length': requestData.getLengthSync()}
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("file upload successful;")
      return void res.status(200).json("got file");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
        // return void res.status(error.response.status).json(error.response.data);
      }
    )
})
```

In my resource server, I am having two problems:

1. I am using body parser to increase the limits of resource body, but its not allowing me to send big files

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));
```

2. I am getting the file as a string. The only way I am getting the file is by doing

> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))

My controller in the Resource-server:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/data/files/',
  limits: { fileSize: 1000000000 }
  // filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  //   cb(null, Date.now() + '.json') //Appending .jpg
  // }
});

const upload = multer(storage)

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/file', upload.any(), function (req, res) {
  ...
});
```

What I would like to actually do is get the file from the request object in my Resource server, and then save the file in the file system. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, i have a question for you, the server that you are using for handle all that code, have the enough resources to handle a > 50 mb file ?

Comment: 50 mb is kind of the upper limit. I am expecting around 4-10 mb files

Answer (score 0):

could be that you have a typo?, in your Resource-server,

```
const upload = multer({ storage });
```